# Double Sigma in Binomial

Tags: binomial-theorem

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/54EMK.jpg)

\begin{equation*}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{r=0}^{k}{C}_{r}^{n+1}
\end{equation*}

I tried solving this double sigma by opening all terms and adding them individually, but it was very tiring, please suggest any other method

Comment: Can you expand on your attempt? Hint: Are there any identities you can use?